# Process and recommendations for obtaining a prepaid micro-SIM card in Ulan Bator, Mongolia

Tags: cellphones, mongolia, ulan-bator

What do I need to to do to obtain a micro-SIM in Ulan Bator, Mongolia?

Specifically:

Will I need to present my passport?

Is there anything I should know about the telecommunications companies, for example, owned by the government?

Recommended places to purchase the SIM, specifically a place with good English speakers.

Any other information that would be helpful to a one time visitor who plans on using a smartphone for about a week?

Answer (score 2):

You will not need a passport of any form of ID to buy a prepaid SIM card in Ulan Bator.

You can purchase a SIM card on the third floor of the Seoul Business Center just across the street from the Chinggis Khan Hotel. I felt like I was applying for a loan (small, private office; person doing the sale spent a lot of time typing in a computer). However, their English was good enough to answer my questions.

They said it would take 30 minutes for the SIM to be activated. I had to go back and have them add some information to my phone to make data work.

I paid in cash. 8,000 Tugriks (~$5.25) gets the SIM and some credit. It seems like telecommunications prices are low in Mongolia.